# Given a child had exactly one cavity, find the probability the child brushes once a day

Tags: probability

The question is:

A dental study compared the number of cavities in relation to the frequency of brushing. Of the $1000$ children surveyed, $15%$ never or rarely brushed, $60%$ generally brush once a day, the rest brush two or more times a day. The number of cavities for each child is a Poisson random variable. Those that brush infrequently average $3$ cavities during the five year testing period, once a day average two cavities, and two or more times average one cavity.

Given a child had exactly one cavity, find the probability the child brushes once a day.

---

My attempt, if you want to call it an attempt. I am trying to learn probability finally because it's the one math course I want to retake.

Let the following be true:
$b_1=$ brushes once a day
$I$ = brushes infrequently (rarely or never)
$b_2$ = brushes twice or more a day
$P(b_1) = .6, P(I)=.15$ and $P(b_2)=.25$

We want $P(b_1|c=1)$

I am unsure about how to incorporate the Poisson into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also know all distributions of $P(c|I), P(c|b_1), P(c|b_2)$, because you know their averages (part of the data) and the distribution (Poisson) is known as well, so you can determine the respective parameters. The  probability $P(b_1|c=1)$ then follows by Bayes' rule.

Comment: I'm not seeing it at all. I don't get how me knowing the averages helps me in any way.

For example I know that with avg of 3 it is $e^{-3}$ but what do I do with this?

Comment: $P(c=k|b_1)$ is given by $\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$ (this is what Poisson-distributed means), with average $\lambda$. So for the $b_1$ case, this is $\lambda=2$. For $I$ as condition, it's $3$, for $b_2$ it's 1. @Nimbus

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to use the Bayes formula: $$P(b_1|c=1) = \dfrac{P(b_1,\, c=1) }{P(c=1)}.$$

Now use law of total probability to find $P(c=1):$ $$P(A) = P(A|B_1)P(B_1)+P(A|B_2)P(B_2)+P(A|B_3)P(B_3),$$
where $A,B_1, B_2, B_3$ are suitable events you need to define. $B_1, B_2, B_3$ must be disjoint and their probabilities must add up to $1.$

Comment: I know I need to use the Baye's formula, the issue is I still don't know where to put the Poisson into play. I don't get when I use it or what the averages are giving me

Comment: You also need $P(c=1 \land b_1) = P(c=1|b_1)P(b_1)$ both of which are computable; the first from the Poisson distribution the second from the first set of statistics.